# Why doesn't a different entry (eg w-70) of progress in Bootstrap than w-25, w-50, w-75 and w100 work and how to achieve it?

Tags: html, progress-bar, bootstrap-5

I'm making progress (using `<div>`) in Bootstrap and I wanted to make progress with **70%**. But when I set `w-70`, the value drops to about 5%. It doesn't even work for example `w-45`, etc. only `w-25`, `w-50`, `w-75` and `w-100`.

My code:

```html
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar w-70 bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">70%</div>
</div>
```

I also looked in the Bootstrap documentation and everywhere there are examples of only, for example, 75%. But I need to set `w-70`, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides [utilities for setting width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/): `.w-25`, `.w-50`, `.w-75`, `.w-100` and `.w-auto`.
There are no intermediate utilities like `.w-70`.

But you can achieve it:

- by using `style="width: 70%"` instead of a class.
- by creating only the `.w-70` class manually in CSS and setting it to `width: 70%`.
- by creating a set of utilities thanks to the [Utility API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/api/).